# Import certificate into Windows key store

Tags: certificates

I am using nShield HSM for signing with MS application/pdf and my own .Net Application. My steps for your information:

- Create PKCS11 key pairs
- Create a MSCAPI container
- Import PKCS11 key into the container

After this, the MS application/pdf or .Net application still can't find the certificate with a link to corresponding private key (in the container)

Comment: This belongs to stackoverflow, really.

Comment: @Stephane On SO this question would be closed as lacking precise steps to reproduce the problem, in particular the code of the application. On this site the question should be closed for the same reason — we can't debug a problem without having steps to reproduce it.

Comment: @Gilles It would still be a better place. This is really specific to how Windows CAPI store works. It's not a bad question though: it can get into describing exactly how that system works and could be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much detail so it's hard to answer but I'd take a few of guesses here:

- You're creating a new store and placing your key there but aren't actually telling your applications to use this store. Remember: by default, application will only look for private keys on the MY (a.k.a. personal) store.
- You're storing the certificates in a different security context as the application. If you use the current user store, for instance, service applications will not be able to see or use them.
- The user contact from which your application runs does not have access to the private key. This is typical of certificates stores in the computer (SYSTEM) user context and accessed through regular users. You need to setup the ACL on the private key for that to work.
- You haven't installed the crypto provider drivers in all relevant systems: the certificates can then still be visible but access to the private key will fail.